# AngularJS, $resource, get the object from .query()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Need get one object from .query(), service:

```
angular.
  module('core.users').
  factory('User', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('users/users.json', {}, {
        query: {
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: true
         }
       });
      }
    ]);
```

component:

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('userDetail').
  component('userDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'user-detail/user-detail.template.html',
    controller: ['$routeParams', 'User', '$filter',
      function TaskDetailController ($routeParams, User, $filter) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.id = parseInt($routeParams["id"], 10);
        vm.users = User.query(function() {
          vm.user = $filter('currentUser')(vm.users, vm.id);
        });
      }
    ],

    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```

need to get one object from array, 'currentUser', with $routeParams id, problem - vm.user is undefined in controller scope, here

```
vm.users = User.query(function() {
  vm.user = $filter('currentUser')(vm.users, vm.id); // all ok, i got the object
  });
console.log(vm.user) // undefined
```

it's ok for view, i can display properties, but need make .put() request to server with this solo object, when some of user props changed...

Comment: your console.log is outside of aysnc request.Please put it inside and see the result getting printed or not

Comment: yep, printed, but how i can get this object out of request? try many ways, but still can't found solution...  or just need make all operations in this request?

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>   [error])

You should write:

```
vm.users = User.query();
vm.users.$promise.then(function(response){
  vm.user = $filter('currentUser')(vm.users, vm.id);
  console.log(vm.user); // Should log the desired result
});
console.log(vm.user); //This will be undefined since it is called before the promise is resolved
```

Comment: yes, it's works, same as my script, but i need got vm.user object in controller scope, out of request. is it possible? :)

Comment: Im not sure I understand, but if you need the value of vm.user to be populated before a certain action, you will need to call that action after the promise has resolved. If you just want `vm.user` to be defined you can declare is as an empty object at the top of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `vm.user`
first and put [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on it.

JS :

```
vm.user = {};

$scope.$watch(function() {
    return vm.user;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {

    console.log(newVal); //you can get new value here which is single object
})

vm.users = User.query(function() {
    vm.user = $filter('currentUser')(vm.users, vm.id); // all ok, i got the object
});
```